# Rundeck liquibase.exception.DatabaseException

Tags: h2, liquibase, rundeck, rhel7

Rundeck was running fine (service active). Version 3.4.10 (no man neither -version command, can't be sure...)

Now it doesn't work (service crashes). The error is
`Network Error (tcp_error) "Connection refused"`

What I have tried : *removed* all database files */var/lib/data/rundeck/rundeckdb.mv.db* and */var/lib/data/rundeck/rundeckdb.trace.db* => it works, however I need my data...

I have tried to copy the DB from an other working rundeck server but I have the same error (however, with an active service this time).
in Service logs : **liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Error executing SQL UPDATE PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK SET LOCKED=TRUE** ...

How to open my H2 database with linux command line **without** java JBoss or related technology ?

Comment: Could you elaborate? Which Rundeck version are you using? What exactly you deleted from /var/lib/data/rundeck? Could you post the full service.log error stack?

Comment: @MegaDrive68k thanks, I updated with more infos, I have found the issue however I am trying to troubleshoot without java...

Comment: Probably you have an invalid backend conf in your rundeck-config.properties. Could you post the rundeck-config.properties file content? (please hide or change any potentially sensitive information.